# How to formulate an array literal of a composite type containing arrays?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, composite

I have a composite type like

```
CREATE TYPE example AS (id integer, some_stuff integer[]);
```

Thought I can use an array of this type as an argument of a function.  The only problem is I couldn't find a way to build an array literal for that...  If I try obtain it from PostgreSQL:

```
WITH elements AS (
    SELECT (12, '{1,2}')::example AS e UNION 
    SELECT (3, '{3,1}')::example 
)
SELECT array_agg(e) FROM elements;
```

I get the following:

```
{"(3,\"{3,1}\")","(12,\"{1,2}\")"}
```

But look:

```
SELECT E'{"(3,\"{3,1}\")","(12,\"{1,2}\")"}'::example[];

ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"(3,"{3,1}")","(12,"{1,2}")"}"
LINE 1: select E'{"(3,\"{3,1}\")","(12,\"{1,2}\")"}'::example[]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using [`ARRAY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) and [`ROW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) constructors:

```
Select array[row(3, array[3,1]), row(12, array[1,2])]::example[];
               array
------------------------------------
 {"(3,\"{3,1}\")","(12,\"{1,2}\")"}
(1 row)
```

If you want solution without using constructors, then use following example:

```
Select E'{"(3,\\"{3,1}\\")","(12,\\"{1,2}\\")"}'::example[];
              example
------------------------------------
 {"(3,\"{3,1}\")","(12,\"{1,2}\")"}
(1 row)
```

As you see main issue here is that you need to write `\\"`, because this effectively means `\"` (using "escape" string syntax) that you saw as output of your first select.

Comment: Thanks!  The only problem is that I must use literals here, the array constructor is not an option.  Fortunately this is a rare case :)